# Bootstrap: trigger popover with a radio button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a guide for the user, where the application prompts them to perform a specific action.

So, for example, when the click on a particular radio button, a popover would appear instructing them which element to select next.

HTML:

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="venue_id[]" id="radio_venue_586" value="586" role="button" data-toggle="popover" /> ABC
</label>
```

jQuery:

```
$("[id^='radio_venue_" + venueID + "']").popover({
    placement: "top",
    title: "Board & Occupancy",
    content: "Please choose a board & occupancy for this venue",
    container: ".venue-1-" + venueID
});
```

I've tried various different types of event and none have so far worked.

Yes, `venueID` is passing a value when the user clicks on the radio button.

```
$('input[name="venue_id[]"]').click(function(event) {
    venueID = $(this).attr("value");

    // alert() works
    alert(venueID);

    // none of the following triggers
    $('[id^="radio_venue_"]').popover({
        placement: "top",
        title: "Board & Occupancy",
        content: "Please choose a board & occupancy for this venue",
        container: ".venue-1-" + venueID
    });

    $("[id^='radio_venue_" + venueID + "']").popover({
        container: ".venue-1-" + venueID
    });

});
```

Is it possible to trigger a popover via a radio button?

Comment: use proper event on radio button and call popover then?

Comment: I've tried everything I can think of and nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Popover seems to work fine on radio button. Just make sure the `container` element exists.

```js
var venueID = 5;

$('[id^="radio_venue_"]').popover({
    placement: "top",
    title: "Board & Occupancy",
    content: "Please choose a board & occupancy for this venue",
    container: ".venue-1-" + venueID
});


$("[id^='radio_venue_" + venueID + "']").popover({
    container: ".venue-1-" + venueID
});
```

```css
label {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<label>
  <input type="radio" name="venue_id[]" id="radio_venue_586" value="586" role="button" />ABC
</label>

<div class="venue-1-5"></div>
```

Comment: I must have something wrong somewhere, because I can't replicate what you've done.

Comment: I've taken your code and move it into the part where venueID is declared and it's not working. I've also edited the opening post to show what I've got. I am mystified.

Comment: so if you click the `venue_id[]` element THEN the radio button, still nothing?

Comment: Yep. I'm trying everything I can think of. Within the click() there are other things using venueID with no problems, but it refuses to run inside the popover(). I have to hard code the ID in for it to work.

Comment: I've trimmed the jQuery file and the <head> down to just the code you've written and it's not working. I have no idea what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

See this working demo: http://www.bootply.com/dxB6Rasx5m

```
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
    placement: "top",
    title: "Board & Occupancy",
    content: "Please choose a board & occupancy for this venue",
    trigger: "click"
});
```

Check for errors in the browser console, and make sure the venueID is defined. Also, the `top` placement maybe a problem if the input is not pushed down by other content.

Comment: I've not seen a single error with any of the attempts I've made. Also, this approach can't work; there are hundreds of hotels to choose from, which is why I'm using the ID value to find which the user chose.

Comment: Make sure you're not binding the popover too early.. before the 100's of id's are created. Do you have the .popover() inside $(document).ready()?

Comment: It needs venueID to figure out which radio button it's supposed to be attached to. As I said in post, venueID is coming through.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a change event on the radio buttons. If the value of the radio button is checked (done by the :checked CSS3 pseudo class), then trigger the popover manually.

Bootstrap offers show / hide / toogle / destroy methods as string parameters.

```
 $("[id^='radio_venue_" + venueID + "']").change(
    function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked') ) {
            $(this).popover('show');
        }
    });
```